# How to fix genymotion error of undefined symbol : drmGetDevice?

Tags: linux, android-emulator, genymotion

When I run :

```
sudo /opt/genymobile/genymotion/genymotion
```

I've got this error :

> Logging activities to file: /root/.Genymobile/genymotion.log
>
> ./genymotion: symbol lookup error:
>   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1: undefined symbol: drmGetDevice

Comment: read the comment of this page: https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/genymotion/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Go to the directory where you have installed genymotion and remove `libdrm.so.2`

Comment: Note that updating genymotion and virtualbox may cause genymotion doesn't work.